# How to download content to a file using Postman script

Tags: postman

I have a requirement to create test data using script and download that test data to a file. Currently, I added test data to a collection variable separated by "|", but I'm not sure how to create a file and send this collection variable data and download to local.

I noticed help on downloading responses using Newman but not directly from Postman. Please help me with this.

I tried using

```js
var element = document.createElement('a');
element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
element.setAttribute('download', filename);
```

However, I get an error:

> ReferenceError: document is not defined